# Typescript not correctly inferring correctly when trying to wrap useMutation in react-query

Tags: typescript, react-query

`react-query` comes with a hook called `useMutation`. I am trying to wrap it in a custom hook like so:

```
function myCustomMutation() {
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: (variables: CustomVariablesType): Promise<CustomResponseType> {
            ...
        }
    })
}
```

This works fine. Typescript infers the correct type for `useMutation` and consequently `myCustomMutation`.  I try and pass through extra `react-query` config. In order to do this, I import `react-query`'s `UseMutationOptions` type, so my code becomes:

```
import { useMutation, UseMutationOptions } from 'react-query';

function myCustomMutation(config: UseMutationOptions) {
    return useMutation({
        ...config,
        mutationFn: (variables: CustomVariablesType): Promise<CustomResponseType> {
            ...
        }
    })
}
```

At this point, I get the following type error:

`Argument of type '{ useErrorBoundary?: boolean | ((error: unknown) => boolean) | undefined; mutationFn: ((variables: CustomVariablesType) => Promise<CustomResponseType>) | MutationFunction<unknown, void>; mutationKey?: MutationKey | undefined; ... 6 more ...; meta?: MutationMeta | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationKey'.`.

It seems like Typescript is picking the wrong overload for `useMutation` since it thinks I am trying to specify a `MutationKey`.

I get a few of these errors, so to simplify, I move the object out into its own object and specify the type:

```
import { useMutation, UseMutationOptions } from 'react-query';

function myCustomMutation(config: UseMutationOptions) {
    const newConfig:UseMutationOptions = {
        ...config,
        mutationFn: (variables: CustomVariablesType): Promise<CustomResponseType> {
            ...
        }
    };

    return useMutation(newConfig);
}
```

Now I get a more specific type error:
`Type '(variables: CustomVariablesType): Promise<CustomResponseType>' is not assignable to type 'MutationFunction<unknown, void>'`

Looking at the type declaration files,

`useMutation` has the following overload:

```
declare function useMutation<TData = unknown, TError = unknown, TVariables = void, TContext = unknown>(options: UseMutationOptions<TData, TError, TVariables, TContext>): UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables, TContext>;
```

Where `mutationFn` in `UseMutationOptions` has the type `MutationFunction<TData, TVariables>`.

My guess is when I specify `newConfig:UseMutationOptions` and don't pass in any of the generic types, I am using the default generic types of `unknown` and `void` specified in the original declaration.

What is the correct way to allow typescript to continue inferring these types while allowing me to pass through my own custom config?

Comment: UseMutationOptions has generics, you can't just leave them out. It is usually not advised to create abstractions where users can pass in all of the options from the outside. One reason is it's quite hard to type correctly. Another reason is that the api you're creating is likely "too wide": the options also contain the mutationFn, and you likely wouldn't want someone to pass that in from the outside...

Comment: Hi @TkDodo. The end goal I'm trying to achieve is to have a hook that makes a certain API call, but I want the caller to be able to pass in any normal options to deal with the results (e.g. onSuccess). Alternatively, I could instead type specific functions that can be passed, but that felt unnecessarily restrictive for an app I'm using to prototype with. 
You are right about not wanting to pass `mutationFn`, but that feels like a simple `Omit` would solve that problem?

Ignoring best practices around API, though, I'm still curious how to generally achieve this in typescript (if possible)

Comment: I also realised in the question I was implying `mutationFn` could be overwritten by the config, I've edited this, since that's not what I mean.